# First-order logic : is this a correct way to say ' x is a power of 2 ' in first order number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, first-order-logic, quantifiers

0 < x ∧ ∀y ((1 < y ∧ ∃z x = y × z) → ∃z y = z + z).

I'm confused about the last part. ∃z y = z + z by itself would be fine, but haven't we already used z? I'm also not clear on free/ bounded variables, so that might also be it.

Also, what is the difference between ∀x∀y F and ∀x (∀y F)? What do the brackets indicate?

Lastly, our professor told us to always consider what variable the statement is about. In this case, it's about x, but we haven't quantified x anywhere..

Comment: There is no difference between $∀x∀y \ F$ and $∀x \ (∀y \ F)$. It can be at most a matetr of readibility.

Comment: You van re-use bound variables with different scopes. But if you want to avoid misunderstanding, you can use different variables: $∀y \ ((1 < y ∧ ∃z \ (x = y × z) → ∃w \ (y = w + w))$.

Comment: $x$ is *free* in the formula; the formula asserts: "if $x$ is greater than $0$, then every proper divisor of $x$ (i.e. a divisor not equal to $1$) is a square". As you can see, in the natural language "translation" there is only one variable left: the free one.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what scope means? Also, how do we decide if the scopes are different?. Lastly, could you perhaps make this into an answer?

Comment: "scope" is the subformula that the leading quantifier is "acting on". In $∀y ((1<y∧∃z (x=y×z)→∃z (y=z+z))$ the scope of $∀y$ is the complete formula. The scope of the leftmost $∃z$ is $(x=y×z)$ while the scope of the rightmost is $(y=z+z)$.